# How to Read .json file in python code from google cloud storage bucket

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to read a `.json` file as `dict()` in a python code from **VM instance** stored in google cloud storage bucket.

I tried reading json file as blob:

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
blob = bucket.get_blob('remote/path/to/file.json')
str_json = blob.download_as_string()
```

But I'm unable to decode the `str_json`. Is my approach correct? if any other approach available please let me know.

I need something like:

```py
# Method to load json
dict = load_json(gcs_path='gs://bucket_name/filename.json')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method using GCS File System `gcsfs` an be used read files from Google Cloud storage.

```py
# Reading gcs files with gcsfs
import gcsfs
import json

gcs_file_system = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="gcp_project_name")
gcs_json_path = "gs://bucket_name/path/to/file.json"
with gcs_file_system.open(gcs_json_path) as f:
  json_dict = json.load(f)
```

This method also works for ***images*** stored in GCS with `skimage` as,

```py
from skimage import io
with gcs_file_system.open(gcs_img_path) as f:
  img = io.imread(f)
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is an alternative way to reach it using the official Cloud Storage library:

```
# Import the Google Cloud client library and JSON library
from google.cloud import storage
import json

# Instantiate a Google Cloud Storage client and specify required bucket and file
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.blob('filename.json')

# Download the contents of the blob as a string and then parse it using json.loads() method
data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution:

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob("blob_name.json")
# here you get string
str_json = blob.download_as_text()
# now you have as dict
dict_result = json.loads(str_json)
```