# How to read and update a field in JSON file that's in Google cloud using Python script

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage

How to read and update a field in JSON file that's in Google cloud using Python script.
I've tried using

```
with open(filepath, 'r')
```

Where filepath was a gs path location

```
gs://bucket-name/path
```

But I was getting `FileNotFoundError`.
Is there any other way to read and update a field in JSON that's in Google cloud using Python?

Comment: If you want to read a file you need to use google cloud storage library.Have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#reading_from)

Comment: Hi @Chithal Glad to hear that it was helpful. I shared my comment as a solution, so that it would be easier to find for others who are facing the same issue.please consider accpeting or upvoting:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read or write a file you will need to use Google Cloud Storage library. The Google Cloud Storage  library is a client library for accessing Google Cloud Storage services. This library provides several methods to interact with objects in Cloud Storage,which also  includes methods for reading and updating the objects.

You can check this document on [Reading and writing to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) for more information and code samples.

Also check the below similar example

[How to Read .json file in python code from google cloud storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708081/how-to-read-json-file-in-python-code-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket)